# Why are polynomial filters for gradients in the opposite sign?

Tags: filters

I was looking at the filters, and the ones for 1st derivatives, gradient http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter#Tables_of_selected_convolution_coefficients
by testing the 9-points one:

```
D=[-4;-3;-2;-1;0;1;2;3;4]/60;
y=sin((0:0.2:6)');
yd = conv(D,y);
plot([repmat(0,128,1) y yd(5:end-4)])
```

[image]

we see that actually `[4;3;2;1;0;-1;-2;-3;-4]/60` would give the right signs, so why is it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the formula above the table you linked to, you see that the output values are computed like

$$Y^{\prime}_j=\sum_{n=-4}^{4}D_ny_{j+n}$$

In Matlab this could simply be implemented by a vector product (for one output value $Y^{\prime}_j$, where the vector $y$ contains the input values around the current index $j$):

```
yd = D'*y;
```

On the other hand, convolution of these sequences is defined by

$$Y^{\prime}_j=\sum_{n=-4}^{4}D_ny_{j-n}$$

(note the '-' sign in the index of $y_j$!). So if you want to use the 'conv()' function in Matlab, you need to flip the coefficients in the vector $D$.